# Sharepoint List Attachments Organizer

Tags: office-365, custom-list, attachments

I have a custom Sharepoint list with attachments enabled. This allows me to upload a number of attachments which display with most recently uploaded files on top. While I know it is not possible to have two attachments columns for a list in Sharepoint, what I do wonder is if it is possible to 'organize' the uploaded files in such a way to create a separation between files so they don't appear in one big unordered list as if there were two attachment columns. I hope my questions is clear, if not I will be happy to clarify! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for attachments to display in 2 columns format versus 1 column format?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti Two columns would be fine, as long as I could somehow control which attachments appear in each column. The goal is when someone views the details of a list item, that they would see two separate 'lists' of attachments. One 'list' would have attachments pertaining to a certain subject, while the other 'list' would have the attachments pertaining to a different subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Display Form or Field on a form using CSR. This will be used to render your field as designed but you have to decide how to categorize your attachments.

The Syntax would be as follows

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Fields: {
      'Attachments': {
        DisplayForm: function(ctx) {
          var html= '';
          var attachments = ctx.CurrentItem.Attachments;
          if(attachments != null) {
            html = "<ul>";
            for(var i = 0; i < attachments.Attachments.length; i++) {
                html += ("<li>" + attachments.Attachments[i].FileName + "</li>");           
            }           
            html += "</ul>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can refer this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms) which explains with an example.

Let me know if you need further help.